# Castle Windsor Typed Factory Weirdness

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, castle

I'm getting some very unexpected (I think) behavior with the Typed Factory facility. Basically, it's reusing transient component instances for constructor injection with `Func<T>`.

Here is the gist of it:

```
// this guy is registered as service EntityFrameworkRepositoryProvider, not IRepository
[Transient] 
public class EntityFrameworkRepositoryProvider : IRepository 
{
    public EntityFrameworkRepositoryProvider(ObjectContext objectContext, Assembly assembly)
    {
         // HOLY MOLY BATMAN!! Every time I hit this constructor when getProvider gets called,
         // I don't actually get the arguments passed into getProvider. I get the 
         // arguments that were passed into getProvider the very FIRST time 
         // it was called...in other words I get the wrong 
         // ObjectContext (for the wrong connection string)...BIG PROBLEM


         // do stuff...
    }
}

[Singleton]
// this guy gets registered on startup
internal class EntityFrameworkRepositoryProviderFactory : IRepositoryProviderFactory
{
      private readonly Func<ObjectContext, Assembly, EntityFrameworkRepositoryProvider> getProvider;

      public EntityFrameworkRepositoryProviderFactory(Func<ObjectContext, Assembly, EntityFrameworkRepositoryProvider> getProvider) 
      {
          this.getProvider = getProvider;
          // do stuff...
      }

      public IRepository CreateRepository()
      {
          var provider = getProvider(new ObjectContext(GetConnectionString()),
              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly);
          // do stuff...
      }

      public string GetConnectionString() 
      { 
             // returns one of a few diff EF connection strings
      }          
}
```

I also have a standard LazyComponentLoader. What am I doing wrong here? What should I do instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was this seemingly harmless code in the LazyComponentLoader:

```
        public IRegistration Load(string key, Type service, IDictionary arguments)
        {
            var component = Component.For(service);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmtpy(key))
            {
                component = component.Named(key);
            }

            if (arguments != null)
            {
                // This makes the typed factory facility screw up. (Merge is an extension method that merges dictionaries)
                component.DynamicParameters((k, d) => d.Merge(arguments));
            }                

            return component;
        }

   public static void Merge(this IDictionary target, IDictionary source)
    {
        foreach (object key in source.Keys)
        {
            target[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
```

Comment: depends how you implement your `Merge` method. If you just add your own arguments to `d`, you should be fine. If you still believe the behavior is somehow flawed or not what you would expect feel free to bring this up for discussion on Castle users group on Google groups

Comment: Good point! The problem is that Merge overwrites I think...so the first set of parameters I Merge() ends up overwriting the second (see impl above).

Comment: ...so maybe the behavior is to be expected (not flawed).